# Add to Cart Success Message Translation issue?

Tags: addtocart, store-view, translate

```
    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__(
    'You added product %1 to the <a href="%2">shopping cart</a>.',
    $block->getData('product_name'),
    $block->getData('compare_list_url')),
    ['a']
);
```

I have a store view of **Sweden** as default
and I want to translate these words in code
*" You added product to  your shopping cart"*

**For this I have created I18n / sv_SE.csv in my child theme folder**

[image]

when I run deploy command this sv_SE is not even deployed in pub  folder

also I run this command

```
php -f bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/TemplateMonster_child/i18n/sv_SE.csv" app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/TemplateMonster_child
```

How can I translate this pop up message??

**Pop up**
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: You can use [Inline translation](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/translate-inline.html) for this. Please try it. Thanks and Happy Coding.

Comment: I have tried that and It displays alphabets in an array

Comment: which popup do you want to translate?

Comment: I have added that pop up

Comment: What is your Magento version and have you override the Magento checkout module? and is your Magento is in production mode?

Comment: I  have MAGNETO 2 AND I don't want to override it . I want  to translate it into Swedish

Comment: I tried to override it  added file Magento_Checkout\template\messages\addCartSuccessMessage.phtml                                 but  then no message was displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to confirm that that language should be selected `Swedish (Sweden)` in 
 for you store/website at "Admin > stores > configuration > General > Locale Options > Locale" field. Otherwise, Magento will load en_US.csv file. Also, flush the Magento cache after all changes.

Also, try to edit your CSV file in a simple text editor and paste below text in it and try after the cache flush.

`"You added %1 to your <a href=""%2"">shopping cart</a>.","tame add %1 to yourssss<a href=""%2"">shopping cart</a>."`

Comment: The locale field is Sweden I have already set this

Comment: The default theme already have en_US.csv in i18n folder

Comment: after creating child theme I uploaded sv_SE.csv in i18n and run deploy can cleared cache but still changes are applied in fact sv_SE is changed to something else and is even not deployed to pub folder

Comment: @HafsaZulfiqar oh okay so you added a new theme, you need run setup upgrade first after that setup di compile and after that deploy the content.

Comment: I am also done with that

Comment: Is your theme applied on front side?

Comment: Yes My custom CSS is working

Comment: can you share your theme with child and parent so I can check it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107577/discussion-between-kunj-and-hafsa-zulfiqar).